# Using the map method make a copy of an array of products with prices reduced 25% and create to a new variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

> ```
> const products = [
>   {
>     name: 'backpack',
>     color: ['red', 'yellow'],
>     price: 500,
>   },
>   {
>     name: 'shirt',
>     color: ['blue'],
>     price: 400,
>   },
>   {
>     name: 'shoes',
>     color: ['red'],
>     price: 1200,
>   },
>   {
>     name: 'socks',
>     color: ['yellow', 'blue'],
>     price: 200,
>   },
>   {
>     name: 'pants',
>     color: ['blue', 'red'],
>     price: 1000,
>   },
> ]
> ```
>
> All of the items are 25% off. Using a `map` method, make a copy of the array products with prices reduced by 25%, then save copy to a new variable called `saleproducts`.

```
const saleProducts = products.map( (element,) =>{
  return element['price'] + .25 / (element['price'] * 10000 )
})
```

I have this but where I'm really stuck is taking 25% off of the price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
products.map((product) =>({ ...product, price: product.price * 0.75 }));
```

P.D. read this:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank!, that helped a lot, also thanks for the additional resources, these higher order methods have  been hard for me to grasp.